# Unable to consume two parameter passing web service in android

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I am trying to consume a web service from android by the method SOAP.
This is the exact web service which i am trying to consume  "http://54.251.60.177/TMSOrdersService/TMSDetails.asmx" .

the input values for this web service are

**FromDate :**    01/01/2012

**ToDate   :**    07/07/2012

But the problem is,

After giving the proper values to that web service, i am getting this 
"XML pull parser exception"

How to over come this issue?

thanks in advance!..

Comment: I hope you are sending the dates in String format and not `java.util.Date`.

Comment: @swayam is this way right?                                          SimpleDateFormat smf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
String FromDate=smf.format(new Date());

Comment: yeah, but why `new Date()` ?  You need to pass an existing Date object instead of creating a new one which represents the current date!

Comment: @swayam can you help me,i probably done some sources for this concept but i am strugling to parse only the xml data......can you help me.......please

Comment: @swayam instead of new Date(),can you tell me what code have i to add for the existing Date..

Comment: Added a code snippet below. Hope that helps.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16510/discussion-between-manick-and-swayam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you are sending the request as a `String` instead of passing a `Date` object.

```
  DateFormat formatter ; 
  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 

  Date date ;  
  date = (Date)formatter.parse("01/01/2012");  // to create a Date object

  String s = formatter.format(date); /// to create the Date to a String
```

**Note :**   **`dd/MM/yyyy`** is the correct format that you should be using.